# Sublime SFTP - Upload only part of local project to remote directory

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible when setting up the sftp.config “Map to remote” file to also map the “local” file?

For example if I have the following project in sublime text:

```
My Project/
    Deploy/
        minified-javascript.js
        minified-css.css
        Index.html
    Source/
        JavaScript/
            Javascript.js
        Css/
            Style.css
        Index.html
    Gruntfile.js
    Project.json
    Sftp.config
```

I can map my the remote server to a specific folder, however in my local files, the only files I actually want to sync are the files within the `deploy` folder. If I try to upload only the files within my `deploy` folder, it automatically creates new folders on the server instead of just uploading the files to the server.

One solution was to move the `sftp.config` file into the `deploy` folder, however anytime I run my build command in `grunt`, the `sftp.config` file is deleted.

Is there an easy to sync only part of a project without keeping the full directory structure on the server?

Answer (score 0):

At this point it is simply not a feature. I have a similar desire to specify the local folder to avoid having the .config file being destroyed every time I run build on the site.

The best recommendation at this point is to email the developer (support@wbond.net) and specify why this would be an advantageous feature. His support site: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/support